# Prevent pushing to master on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, branch, access-control, pull-request

GitHub allows you to configure your repository so that [users can't force push to master](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks), but is there a way to prevent pushing to master entirely? I'm hoping to make it so that the only way of adding to commits to master is through the GitHub pull request UI.

Comment: `repo settings -> branch restrictions`. But you have to pay for a teams account.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Since the original question / answer, Github has added a new option for this to the restricted branches UI which allows you to set this up.

> **Require pull request reviews before merging** When enabled, all commits must be made to a non-protected branch and submitted via a
> pull request with the required number of approving reviews and no
> changes requested before it can be merged into a branch that matches
> this rule.

To find it go to Settings > Branches > Branch Protection Rules
and click 'Add Rule'.
[image: Github UI after following instructions]
Then, enter the name of the branch you want to protect and click the checkbox to require pull request reviews before merging.
[image: Github UI with the button to click]
By default, this only stops people who are not moderators. There is also another checkbox later down for ensuring that even moderators cannot merge.
[image: Github UI with the other button to click]

Comment: This forces a review when merging but doesn't stop from directly committing and pushing to master. At least on my repo.

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe you also have to protect the branch?

Comment: On Github, pattern matching the branch seems to automatically "protect the branch", although doesn't seem to work. Although its a private repository, so I wonder if it might be an issue on Github...?

Comment: @Damien Have you set the "Include administrators" flag? Because if not, you should still be able to directly push to master. Alternatively you could test pushing as different user without admin rights.

Comment: What if I don't want to require reviews? I want only pull requests to be merged to the main branch. I don't care about the status of the pull request.

Comment: Protected branches are available to Pro, Team, and Enterprise users on private repos, not for free users

Comment: Suppose there is no PR required, then is there any way to prevent user from pushing if there is a commit that his push is missing?

Comment: Is this free or paid feature?

Comment: It looks like the option is now called "Do not allow bypassing the above settings".

Answer (score 149):

The current accepted answer is actually correct but if you are an organization owner or have admin privileges, which is the case if you created the repo, you can still push to protected branches. From Github documentation at https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-branch-restrictions:

> Organization owners and people with admin permissions for a repository are always able to push to a protected branch.

For any other type of collaborator, `git push` will fail.

If you really want to disable pushing at all, then you have to set that up locally either by configuring an invalid `pushRemote` for a branch as mentioned before:

`git config branch.master.pushRemote no_push`

or by creating a pre-push hook as shown here: https://gist.github.com/vlucas/8009a5edadf8d0ff7430

Comment: another pre-push hook for the same rationale: https://github.com/219-design/git_templatedir/blob/master/hooks/pre-push

Comment: Have to mention that `pushRemote` way only applies when you are pushing in terminal using git command, if you are using IntelliJ like me to push, it is still working

Answer (score 21):

Directly pushing to remote's master is rejected when [status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-status-checks/) are enabled, meaning that the only way to add commits on remote's master is merging pull requests (which pass the status checks) on GitHub.

Here is my experiment result for the master branch requiring status checks:

1. Create a commit on the master branch on my PC.
2. Push to remote's master.
3. A rejection message appears. The commit is not pushed to remote in the end.

```
C:\GitRepo\GitHub\TomoyukiAota\photo-location-map [master ↑1]> git push
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 305 bytes | 305.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: 3 of 3 required status checks are expected.
To https://github.com/TomoyukiAota/photo-location-map.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/TomoyukiAota/photo-location-map.git'
C:\GitRepo\GitHub\TomoyukiAota\photo-location-map [master ↑1]>
```

Comment: Works for me as a repo administrator with *Include administrators* enabled.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using free-plan on private repo in Github, you may not be able to use protected branch feature. So you need to block any push / commit from local.

This is what I did to make it work locally and distributed to all repo's members.

First of all, you need to install husky to control pre-commit and pre-push hook.
Then, I made a pre-push bash script and commit it inside the repository. Then call this script from husky pre-push hook with husky parameter.

This is my husky configuration inside `package.json` (you can set separated config if you want)

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "./commands/pre-commit",
        "pre-push": "./commands/pre-push $HUSKY_GIT_STDIN"
    }
},
```

as you can see I have 2 scripts, one for pre-push and one for pre-commit.

And this is my `commands/pre-push` bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "===\n>> Talenavi Pre-push Hook: Checking branch name / Mengecek nama branch..."

BRANCH=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
PROTECTED_BRANCHES="^(master|develop)"

if [[ $1 != *"$BRANCH"* ]]
then
  echo -e "\n You must use (git push origin $BRANCH) / Anda harus menggunakan (git push origin $BRANCH).\n" && exit 1
fi

if [[ "$BRANCH" =~ $PROTECTED_BRANCHES ]]
then
  echo -e "\n Cannot push to remote $BRANCH branch, please create your own branch and use PR."
  echo -e " Tidak bisa push ke remote branch $BRANCH, silahkan buat branch kamu sendiri dan gunakan pull request.\n" && exit 1
fi

echo -e ">> Finish checking branch name / Selesai mengecek nama branch.\n==="

exit 0
```

The script basically will do 2 things:

- This script will block anybody who tries to push to a certain branch (in my case I don't want anybody -including myself- to push directly to `master` and `develop` branch). They need to work in their own branch and then create a pull request.
- This script will block anybody who tries to push to a branch that is different from their current active branch. For example you are in branch `fix/someissue` but then you mistakenly type `git push origin master`.

For more detailed instructions you can follow from this article:
https://github.com/talenavi/husky-precommit-prepush-githooks

Answer (score 11):

You can [enable branch restrictions](https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) and decide who (in terms of users and teams of the organization) are allowed to push.

https://help.github.com/articles/about-branch-restrictions/

«Note: If the "Include administrators" is checked and you've enabled required status checks on the branch and they fail, any attempt to push changes to the base branch will also fail, regardless of a user or team's permission status.»

Comment: But is it possible to prevent push from local to remote, and only accept merging per Pull-Request on the Github UI?

Comment: Fwiw, to prevent pushing to master locally, you can add the following to your git config: `git config branch.master.pushRemote no_push`.

Comment: @marvhock this is now possible (just added an answer)

Answer (score 11):

> I'm hoping to make it so that the only way of adding to commits to master is through the GitHub pull request UI.

I have a solution that prevents pushing to the main branch and doesn't require approvals or long status checks to pass in the pull request.

The trick is to create a status check that passes immediately.

Create the following GitHub Action in `.github/workflows/requirePullRequest.yml`.

```yaml
name: require pull request

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  job:
    name: require pull request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo hello
```

Next, update repository settings to require `require pull request` status check to pass.

If you want administrators to follow the same rule, then you have to check `include administrators` rule.

This way, GitHub will reject all direct pushes to the main branch and pull requests won't be delayed by anything.

Comment: Heads up for non-paying users: This is a premium feature in Github, under Settings>Branch. If you don't have a paid version of Github, this may not be the solution you want.

Answer (score 11):

I needed to avoid to accidentally push any commits to master branch.
It is a similar solution like @christian-chandra's but more simple.

go to your local working copy and

```
$ cd .git/hooks
echo '' > pre-commit
$ chmod +x pre-commit
```

Add this content to the file (pre-commit)

```
#!/bin/sh

branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
  echo "Master Branch commit is blocked"
  exit 1
fi
```

done!

Comment: good for accidental pushes, but it can be bypassed very easily by deleting the hook from .git directory.

Comment: So this only works on linux an MacOS?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I don't use windows for 22 years so I cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using Node, You can use [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) to create a pre-push validation that a direct push to master does not happen. That way, You can still use your administrator privileges to merge PRs. I guess other languages have similar solutions to husky.

1. `npm install husky --save-dev`
2. In `/.huskyrc.js`:

```
const preventPushToMaster = `branch=\`git symbolic-ref HEAD\`
if [ "$branch" = "refs/heads/master" ]; then
    echo "\\033[31mDirect push to master is not allowed.\\033[0m"
    exit 1
fi`;

module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    'pre-push': preventPushToMaster,
  },
};
```