# Trunk Based Dev - Cherry picking from trunk to protected branch

Tags: git, github

My dev team is looking to adopt more of a scaled trunk-based development style for our git strategy, with the idea being:

- We maintain a single trunk that is always deployable to production
- Short-lived (day or two) feature branches are created off trunk
- Once feature branch is complete, a pull request is created, approved and merged back into the trunk

At this point we're facing some trouble with how we manage releases. Worth noting we do 2 week sprints with a release at the end.

I believe ideally we would create a release branch off the trunk. Any extra feature branches that are merged and to be included in the release would then be cherry picked into the release branch.

The problem is we would want the release branch to be protected so we can't push any old commit to it. We would only want to cherry pick and push 'merge commits' from the trunk.

A quick search didn't offer any solutions, as it seems it's either protected completely or not at all. We could create another pull request to go from trunk to release branch but that seems a hassle.

My question is are there any options for allowing only certain kinds of commits (merge commits) to be pushed to protected branches? Git hooks? Actions?

If it's relevant we use GitHub.

Comment: FYI what you're describing isn't trunk-based dev.

Comment: And what's the question here?

Comment: I believe what I'm describing is called Scaled Trunk-Based Development (https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com). The release branch would be created early in the sprint and features to be included in the release would be cherry picked in (https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/).

I agree, I posed the question as rather opinionated. I guess question is any options for allowing only certain kinds of commits (merge commits) to be pushed to protected branches? Git hooks? Actions?

Comment: But that isn't what the Question says. And it still doesn't. Edit the Question so it asks a question. And keep in mind that GitHub is not Git.

Comment: If you cherry-pick, it is no longer a merge-commit, but a regular commit

Comment: Apparently you can tell GitHub to only allow commits on whatever main branch through their shiny green merge button. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57685576/1725151)

Comment: you're describing GITFLOW process. You have different branches based on release and production (main), Main is always in the clients hands and release is whats being staged for the next main merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I've found is to use [GitHub's rulesets feature](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets). This allows us to define rules on branches, but not necessarily protect the branch.

We can use this to add a rule to branches that match `release/*` to ensure the commit message starts with 'Merge pull request' which is the default commit message when merging a feature branch into the trunk through a pull/merge request (e.g. `Merge pull request #17 from My-Project/ABC-001`).

Of course developers could still create a commit matching that pattern but it's at least some protection.

[image: Image showing an example of using a rule.]